# Need to capture two values from a drop-down list and post them to a PHP function

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a simple MSSQL table with three columns: Name, Email, Type.

The "Type" column is just a number from 1-9 that identifies the type of approver.

I have a drop-down list in my application that is populated from the above table.

```
<?php 
  echo "<select name=\"approvEmail\">";
  $list = $con->prepare("SELECT ApproverName, ApproverEmail, ApproverType FROM         
      ApproverList");
  $list->execute();
  while($row = $list->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
  {
       echo "<option value='".$row['ApproverEmail']."'>".$row['ApproverName']."
       </option> ";
  }
  echo "</select>";
  ?>
```

The user selects the name of the person he wants to mail the form to, and the back-end function uses the ApproverEmail value to send it. No problems there. But I also need to pick up the ApproverType when the user is selected, and I'm less clear on how to do that. It needs to be a separate POST variable for use elsewhere in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to go back to the database to get the `ApproverType`.**

Even if you created a second field in your form and found a way to synchronize its value, say with Javascript, you'd still have a problem if users ever decided to hack this.  What if they changed the ApproverType submission?  You're trusting a client form with this information and it's a calculated value, so that's not appropriate.

The proper way to handle this is to do another SQL query in the submission script: `'SELECT ApproverType FROM ApproverList WHERE ApproverEmail = '.$_POST['ApprovEmail']`.  This ensures that you always get the appropriate type.

To take this one step further, if there is an auto-increment primary key on the `ApproverList` table, you might want to use this instead of the `ApproverEmail` field for the value of this drop-down.  It's always faster to retrieve this record from the database by primary key, and you can easily retrieve the email when you retrieve the type.

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this make your custom attribute

```
echo "<option apporverType='".$row['ApproverType']."'  value='".$row['ApproverEmail']."'>".$row['ApproverName']."
       </option> ";
```